# How can I flick/swipe a sprite without dragging it?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

Ok so currently in my game, I can drag, swipe, and flick the node. However, I want the user to only be able to swipe/flick the node, and I don't want the user to be able to drag the node. How can I do this?

Here is my current code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if ball.frame.contains(location) {
            touchPoint = location
            touching = true
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch!.location(in: self)
    touchPoint = location

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        touchPoint = location
        if touching {
            if touchPoint != ball.position {
                let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/60.0
                let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-ball.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-ball.position.y)
                let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
                ball.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
            }
        }   
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touching = false

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        touchPoint = location
        let node = self.atPoint(location)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm guessing: your goal is to have the node not move until the finger is released from the swipe gesture, at which point the rate and distance of the finger's movement across the screen determines the rate and direction of travel of the node?

Answer (score 1):

This is why `UIGestureRecognizers` exists.  Add an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on your view, and use the `velocity(in:UIView)` method to let you know the direction and speed of the flick.

Please note, you can't put gestures on nodes, only views, so you will need to convert from view coordinates, to scene coordinates, if you only use the gesture.

You can also allow the gesture's touch to trickle down to the scene, to allow for normal touch calls, and just use the velocity of the pan gesture.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer